# Are there any pitfalls when replacing a Python module using sys.modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a current project of mine, I have decided to not put any significant amount of code in `__init__.py` files, simply because I don't like them. In my head, an `__init__.py` file is just there to inform Python that the folder is a module. I keep forgetting that they might contain lots of code just like any other Python module.

In this project I have decided to create a "main" submodule whenever I'm tempted to put significant amounts of code in an `__ini__.py` file, then I import the "main" submodule in `__init__.py` and replace the module.

---

For example, say I have a module named `alpha`:

```
alpha/
  __init__.py
```

And I want to put a few constants and helper methods under the `alpha` module. Instead of putting the code into `__init__.py` I create a new module called (for example) `main`:

```
alpha/
  __init__.py
  main.py
```

Then I put my stuff in that module. Then I just put this into `__init__.py`:

```
import sys
import alpha.main

sys.modules["alpha"] = alpha.main
```

Now I can put stuff into `alpha/main.py`:

```
author = "John Hancock"
maintainer = "John Hancock"
```

And access it like this:

```
import alpha

print(alpha.maintainer)
```

It works perfectly, and I'm loving that I don't have to edit `__init__.py` files anymore.

---

However, this kind of "magic" always gives me the feeling that a more experienced Python ninja would chop me in the face if he caught me.

This convention seems completely innocuous to me, but could it come back to bite me in the ass later? Are there any pitfalls I should look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that doesn't abuse python so much, is to put the following in your `__init__.py`

```
from .main import *
```

Its not quite the same as replacing the module, but I would suspect it will work in most cases.

However, I would take the theory that you shouldn't do it. Pretending that your code is in the root of the alpha module when it is isn't just confusing.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing now, because a few minutes after I posted the question I noticed that I couldn't import other submodules anymore. I got the error "alpha is not a package", which totally makes sense. I tried deleting the question but you had already answered :P

Comment: Ah, yes, that would break.